# Convert to numeric colums of a dataframe with apply = AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'apply'

Tags: python, pandas, list, apply

I want to convert the columns of this list to numeric using the pandas.to_numeric function, catching the errors and force the conversion by supplying errors='coerce' as an argument for pandas.to_numeric :

```
wrong_type_columns = ['DewPointHighF', 'DewPointAvgF', 'DewPointLowF', 'HumidityHighPercent', 
                      'HumidityAvgPercent', 'HumidityLowPercent', 'SeaLevelPressureHighInches', 
                      'SeaLevelPressureAvgInches' ,'SeaLevelPressureLowInches', VisibilityHighMiles',
                      'VisibilityAvgMiles', 'VisibilityLowMiles', 'WindHighMPH', 'WindAvgMPH', 
                      'WindGustMPH', 'PrecipitationSumInches']
```

I'll try this code:

```
wrong_type_columns = wrong_type_columns.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce', axis=1).astype(int)
```

but i get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'apply'
```

Comment: `wrong_type_columns` is a list. It does not have the method `apply`. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I'm triyng to change those columns of the df austin_weather.csv to numeric, beacuse are object

Comment: can you provide some dummy data ? it will be good for us to provide you better solution.

Comment: Try `df[wrong_type_columns].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce', axis=1).astype(int)`

Comment: Sorry @k33da_the_bug i started typing the answer the same time that you were posting and did not see it until you posted... I apologize

Comment: @PaulBrennan no problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
cols = ['DewPointHighF', 'DewPointAvgF', 'DewPointLowF', 'HumidityHighPercent', 
        'HumidityAvgPercent', 'HumidityLowPercent', 'SeaLevelPressureHighInches', 
        'SeaLevelPressureAvgInches' ,'SeaLevelPressureLowInches', 'VisibilityHighMiles',
        'VisibilityAvgMiles', 'VisibilityLowMiles', 'WindHighMPH', 'WindAvgMPH', 
        'WindGustMPH', 'PrecipitationSumInches']
df[cols] = df[cols].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
```

to see if this gives you what you want.

Comment: It works perfectly, thanks